# Changing Geographic Data to Grid Form in R

Tags: r, data-structures, plyr

Right now I am cleaning up some No2 emission data in U.S, and the format of the data is like:

```
lat long no2

xxx xxx  xxx

xxx xxx  xxx

xxx xxx  xxx
```

But what I want eventually is a data matrix with latitude as row names and longitude as column names, such as

```
     long1 long2 long3 ...
lat1 xxxx  xxxx  xxxx
lat2 xxxx  xxxx  xxxx
lat3 xxxx  xxxx  xxxx
...
```

Also, since I don't necessarily have data for each cell in the matrix above, I want the places with missing data marked "0".

What I previously did was:

```
one <- read.table(files[1], header = TRUE, sep = ",")
one <- one[,1:3]
row_name <- seq(25.05,49.95, by = 0.1)
col_name <- seq(-124.95, -65.05, by = 0.1)
a <- matrix(0, length(row_name), length(col_name))
data_matrix <- data.frame(a)
row.names(data_matrix) <- row_name
names(data_matrix) <- col_name

for (i in 1: dim(one)[1]){
    lat <- as.character(one[i,]$lat)
    long <- as.character(one[i,]$long)
    data_matrix[lat,long] <- one[i,]$no2 
}
```

This method is apparently slow and inefficient, since basically what I did is go through the entire matrix and fill in the blanks cell by cell.

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me solve this!

Comment: If I just wrote `xtabs` it would have been enough characters to be accepted as a comment, but that one function may do it all for you. Instead of creating a dummy matrix, why not post a small corner of your data?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here: http://bit.ly/SORepro   -  [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a guess (although it's areasonably good guess)  until you post some data but until that happens consider this:

```
 grid_mat <- xtabs( no2 ~ lat +lon, data=one)
```

Comment: Actually this already solves the problem perfectly. Thank you so much!